# Looking for a complete table of minerals for a database

Tags: geology, geochemistry, mineralogy

I am building an open source spatial geochemical/geological observational database for mineral exploration.  I need to fill the mineral lookup table.

Where can I find a complete list of all minerals and mineral-groups, chemical formula, Strunz and/or Dana number, or any other data.

I want the Strunz and/or Dana numbers so I can query the data and recode the data based upon mineral groups.

Comment: Are you familiar with http://www.mindat.org/ and http://webmineral.com/ ?

Comment: I am but there is no clear simple way to download the data.  I actually got the feeling that they don't want people to download their data, just use the Web interface

Comment: Did you ask them? Try contacting the people behind it

Comment: http://nrmima.nrm.se/IMA_Master_List_2016-03.pdf Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Would the Elsevier Mineral and Rock table help you out? Link here: http://www.sdgs.usd.edu/pubs/Scans/Elseviers%20mineral%20and%20rock%20table.jpg Note that it's a 20mb jpeg, so maybe right-click>Save As to avoid browser crashes

Comment: The question might be worth putting on [opendata.se] as well (tread carefully - posting across several SE sites is not appreciated).

Comment: the International Mineralogical Association had recognized about 5,400 minerals. About 30 to 50 new minerals are described and one or two minerals are discredited each year

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the source from nrmima.nrm.se/IMA_Master_List_2016-03.pdf, I discovered the:
IMA Database of Mineral Properties
Created and maintained by the RRUFF Project in partnership with the IMA
http://rruff.info/ima/

I downloaded all the minerals in a csv file.  This worked very well for two reasons.  First they had various chemical formula formats that were favorable for entry into a database.  Second they had a mineral group column.  The mineral group column was very important since often in the field the exact mineral is not noted but a group such as chlorite or garnet.  I will worry about Strunz or Dana numbers/codes at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no such thing as a totally comprehensive list of minerals because nobody agrees upon what constitutes a mineral, as opposed to a multiple variants of the same mineral. There is also a grey area between 'natural' and 'synthetic'.
That said, however, the international centre for diffraction data (i.e. for X-ray powder diffraction work) has a recent catalogue of minerals called PDF-4 +2015, which includes more than 365,000 entries! You may have to sift through the catalogue to determine which are genuinely natural minerals that you want in your own catalogue. The '-4' indicates actual minerals as opposed to pharmaceuticals etc, which are under a different catalogue. 
You can access their flyer from:

http://www.icdd.com/products/flyers/PDF-4plus.pdf

Comment: There are clear definitions as to what is a mineral, as opposed to variants of the same mineral. These definitions are being constantly updated as well. The grey area between 'natural' and 'synthetic' is extremely tiny and limited to just a few minerals that were first discovered in anthropogenic settings. For more info: http://nrmima.nrm.se/